# R - Error: Dependency 'leaps' (or dplyr) is not available for package xxx

Tags: r

I'm sorry for the simple question but I'm trying to build my first R package but run into trouble when trying to declare which external packages need to be installed before my R scripts should be run.

If I add a line 
Imports: leaps 
In my DESCRIPTION file

And add the line 
library(leaps) 
into my script it gives me the error: 
Error: Dependency 'leaps' is not available for package xxx
when trying to build and reload my custom package.
Leaps is has not been installed previously but obviously the code runs through when using install.packages()

This is under R 3.4.2

Any suggestions what I am missing? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, to add to the before but I wanted to say, that the same error persists also for all other packages like dplyr and also if I use Depends: dplyr instead of Imports: dplyr.

A code example of both the Description and the Name file is below:

DESCRIPTION

```
Package: test123
Type: Package
Title: What the Package Does (Title Case)
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: The package maintainer <yourself@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
    Use four spaces when indenting paragraphs within the Description.
License: What license is it under?
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Imports: dplyr
Remotes: url::https://cran.rstudio.com
```

hello.R

```
hello <- function() {
  print("Hello, world!")
}
```